# add onchange to <select>

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I want to add an `onchange` function to my created select, but it didn't work. Does someone know how you add `onchange` to a select? This is my code:

```
   function maandgen(){

    var ma = document.createElement("select");
    ma.id='kies';
    ma.onchange='change';
```

Comment: If you want to add a function, why are you adding a string? If you have an existing function named `change`, then just drop the quotes. `ma.onchange=change;`

Comment: with the fist line i create the element <select> in html and it add a id but the onchange dont work. i thought to do it the same why like i did on the second line. the id worked well.

Comment: I suggest to read http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn the basics about event handling first.

Comment: [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a function to onchange property of newly created element.
    and Add that to document as well

```
function maandgen(){

    var ma = document.createElement("select");
    ma.id='kies';
    ma.onchange= changefunction; 
    document.appendChild(ma);

}

function changefunction(){

   alert("changed");

}
```

> i want to use the value of my option in my function howe can i to
>   that?

if you want to pass an argument or "this" to function you can do

replace

```
ma.onchange= changefunction;
```

with

```
ma.setAttribute('onchange', 'changefunction(this)');
```

and now change function becomes

```
function changefunction(item) {
    var value = item.value;  
}
```

Comment: Of course the element has to be added to the document as well.

Comment: @A.B i want to use the value of my option in my function howe can i to that? i have tried  ma.onchange= changefunction(this.value) and function changefunction(month){ but it dont work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function maandgen(){
    var ma = document.createElement("select");
    ma.id='kies';
    ma.onchange= function() {/* write your action here */};
};
```

Comment: Since the OP appears to be a beginner, I'm sure they also appreciate an explanation of the problem / solution.

Comment: @Chilipote thanx for your help:) didnt know you can do it this way too:) i have learned now:D

Comment: @FelixKling, yeah you write, I'll know for next time, thanks, beginner here too

Comment: @Eses, the onchange, is an attribute attach to select element. This attribute has to be a function, that will be executed on the change of the element. It the same thing if you want to add a onclick function for example